# while in production, deploy static files, but style changes aren't visible if we don't clean pub/static folder first

Tags: magento2

We are making style changes while working in developer mode.

Then we push the files to our server which is in `production`.

Then we run 
`$ magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

but the changes aren't showing.

If we first delete folders in pub/static and then run `$ magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` then the changes **are** showing up.

**What command** can we run on our production server to **first clean the pub/static folder**? I don't think it is safe to run `rm -rf pub/static/*` every time we push to production

Comment: It is **never** safe to run `rm -rf whatever/*` in root. You never know what might happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that if you run

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
grunt clean
```

first and then

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

it will work, but that's not ideal, as you don't need grunt on your production server.

I would prefer a **magento** command if someone can post an answer.

Comment: `grunt clean` removes the pub/static/contents as well, so there's no difference in there. You should just remove `pub/static/Vendor/Theme/` if you only want to see your theme's changes.

Comment: @TimondeGroot and how do you do that with a magento command?

Comment: There's no magento command for that. Keep in mind that `grunt` probably isn't installed on production. That's why you'd be better off with a simple `rm -rf pub/static/*/` for now.

Comment: @TimondeGroot that's not an option for automatic deployment, but if there is nothing better, I prefer having grunt on production then. Thanks!